# Correlation among two variables shared by a third set of variables

Tags: regression, correlation, partial-correlation

I am interested in a measure that quantifies the correlation between two variables X,Y that is also shared by a third set of variables Z.

That is, a measure that is in some way the converse of the partial correlation of X,Y when controlling for Z.

A practical way  (yet without a proper theoretical justification why this should work) that I have for calculating this is calculating the correlation of the regression coefficients of X to each variable of Z to the regression coefficients of Y to each variable of Z.

Is there another way of calculating this or a statistical measure that quantifies this type of correlation?

Answer (score 0):

[Regression commonality analysis](http://www.mlrv.ua.edu/2010/vol36_1/Nimon_proof_2.pdf) could be useful as the commonality coefficients indicate a predictor's contribution to a regression effect relative to the other predictor variables in the model. If you regress a Y on X and Z you could break down the common effects of the predictors to examine which ones share variance in predicting the dependent variable as well as to quantify how much variance is shared between independent variables. This is also nicely explained in the link provided